# Apply QChainage based on field value

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm quite new to QGIS and found the great plugin QChainage.

Simply put, it allows to create points along lines.
There are different modes available. Create points every X meters or Divide the line i X number of parts.

What I would need to do is to choose how many parts the line should be split into, according to a column named for example "Parts".

How could I achieve something like that (perhaps using the build in QGIS python console)?

Comment: Not an immediate solution, but you can request a new feature on the [plugin's github page](https://github.com/mach0/qchainage/issues).